# web3py Force send eth transaction at the same block without conformation or any errors

Tags: blockchain, web3.py, cpp-ethereum

My question is how to force send a transaction via `web3` or any other way without paying attention to errors. I know that I will pay for the commission if I am not successful and that will suit me. I'm trying to get into the same `block` with another transaction, and in the case of sending via `web3`, I'm faced with the problem that the node does not update the balance for pending transactions. And, accordingly, my transaction also cannot go online `until the block is completed`. I have seen many times that other bots can do this, so I guess I need to force the transaction and then everything will work. I will be grateful for any help!

`here my simple code`:

```
tx = {
   'chainId': int(web3.eth.chain_id),
   'from': sender,
   'to': receiver,
   'value': int(value),
   'nonce': int(nonce),
   'gas': 21000,
   'gasPrice': int(gas_price.quantize(Decimal('1'), rounding=ROUND_DOWN))
}
signed = web3.eth.account.sign_transaction(tx, pk)
web3.eth.send_raw_transaction(raw)
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to increase the transaction gas compared to the transaction that you want to sandwich. For example, scan the newly pending minted transaction in the mempool => get its gas and gasPrice parameters => then, set your transactions with higher gas and gasPrice => as a consequence, your transaction will appear in the same block with that one and should appear first.

Comment: yep, but again i got this error
`insufficient funds for gas * price + value` cuz block doesn't complete